# Calculate percentage based on multiple groups

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
gender <- c("Man","Man","Woman","Woman")
answer <- c("staying","leaving","staying","leaving")
count <- c(172,25,258,52)
df <- data.frame(gender,answer,count)
```

So basically I want to calculate the percentage of those who are leaving grouped by gender. So for man: 25/(25+172)*100, woman: 52/(52+258)*100

Desired dataframe:

```
gender <- c("Man","Man","Woman","Woman")
answer <- c("staying","leaving","staying","leaving")
count <- c(172,25,258,52)
percentage_of_leaving <- c(12.69,12.69,16.77,16.77)
df <- data.frame(gender,answer,count,percentage_of_leaving)
```

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to do this on a bigger dataset where the answer variable contains only "staying" and "leaving".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Percentage in a dataframe according to groups R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354701/calculate-percentage-in-a-dataframe-according-to-groups-r)

Comment: Using `dplyr` version >=1.1.0 try `mutate(df, perc_leaving = 100 * count[answer == "leaving"] / sum(count), .by = gender)`?

Comment: @Ben This looks so much better! Just one addition for the edge case of no `answer == "leaving"`: `mutate(df, perc_leaving = ifelse(sum(count) == count[answer == "staying"], 0, 100 * count[answer == "leaving"] / sum(count)), .by = gender)`

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little messy and relies on `dplyr` but it works:

```
require(tidyverse)

df.intermediate <- df %>% 
  group_by(gender, answer) %>% 
  summarize(subtotal = sum(count), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% # one could remove this line if one doesn't use .groups = "drop"; I prefer being explicit
  mutate(percentage_of_leaving = subtotal/sum(subtotal)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(answer == "leaving") %>% 
  select(gender, percentage_of_leaving)

df %>% full_join(
  df.intermediate, 
  by = "gender"
)

# output
  gender  answer count percentage_of_leaving
1    Man staying   172             0.1269036
2    Man leaving    25             0.1269036
3  Woman staying   258             0.1677419
4  Woman leaving    52             0.1677419
```

Note that in the case of one gender only having `answer == "staying"`, this will result in `"NA"` for `percentage_of_leaving`. This can be replaced easily with `mutate(percentage_of_leaving = replace_na(percentage_of_leaving, 0)`. For the other case of only `answer == "leaving"`, it will correctly display `1`.